# Why arrays in Immutable.js records are mutable?

Tags: javascript, record, immutable.js

I noticed that in the following piece of code

```
const TaskRecord = new Immutable.Record({
  name: '',
  requiredFor: [],
});

class Task extends TaskRecord {
}

const task = new Task();
```

`task.requiredFor` is really an array (calling `get('requiredFor')` inside the Task class yields the same result) and doesn't get converted to Immutable.List... this way the record isn't immutable.

**Why it is this way? How to fix this?**

Comment: It's only the `Immutable.Record` that is immutable. You cannot fix it, it is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like making magic in constructor does the job:

```
class Task extends TaskRecord {

   constructor(values) {
       super(Immutable.fromJS(values));
   }

}
```